# Ocaml Map to_seq usage

Tags: dictionary, iterator, ocaml

Say I have the following

```
module IntPairs =
   struct
     type t = int * int
     let compare (x0,y0) (x1,y1) =
       match Stdlib.compare x0 x1 with
           0 -> Stdlib.compare y0 y1
         | c -> c
   end

module PairsMap = Map.Make(IntPairs)
```

And I add a few elements:

```
let m = PairsMap.(empty |> add (1,1) 1 |> add (2,1) 1 |> add (1,2) |> add (2,2))
```

How would i use to_seq to print keys in ascending order? 
I'm not to familiar with iterators in ocaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a request for OCaml tutoring than a question about a specific problem in your code. It would generally be faster to read the documentation than to ask individual questions here on StackOverflow.

With that said, the `Seq` interface looks like this:

```
type 'a t = unit -> 'a node
and 'a node = Nil | Cons of 'a * 'a t
val empty : 'a t
val return : 'a -> 'a t
val map : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a t -> 'b t
val filter : ('a -> bool) -> 'a t -> 'a t
val filter_map : ('a -> 'b option) -> 'a t -> 'b t
val flat_map : ('a -> 'b t) -> 'a t -> 'b t
val fold_left : ('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b t -> 'a
val iter : ('a -> unit) -> 'a t -> unit
```

As you can see, it offers many higher-order traversal functions. The one you would want to use is probably `iter` since you want to print the values rather than calculate with them. I.e., there is no return value for your desired usage.

However, you should note that the `Map` interface already has an `iter` function. As near as I can tell, there's no reason to convert to a sequence before doing your iteration. The `Map.iter` documentation says this:

> The bindings are passed to f in increasing order with respect to the ordering over the type of the keys.

This is what you want, so `Map.iter` seems like it will do the trick.

```
PairsMap.iter my_print_function m
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but to expand on what Jeffrey has said, sequences don't really make sense here. Sequences provide a means to iterate over collections of data in a lazy manner. Consider a scenario where I want to multiply every element in a list by two and then print them all.

```
# let lst = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5] in
  lst
  |> List.map (( * ) 2)
  |> List.iter (Printf.printf "%d\n");;
2
4
6
8
10
- : unit = ()
```

This generates a whole new list and then iterates over *that* list and prints each element. But I didn't need the intermediate list. I never used it for anything after printing it. In this case, creating a new list is trivial, but it might not be as the size of the list increases.

If we use sequences, we can insert a print to see that the fact that the mapping occurs only when it needs to.

```
# let lst = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5] in
  lst
  |> List.to_seq
  |> Seq.map (fun x -> print_endline "map"; x * 2)
  |> Seq.iter (Printf.printf "%d\n");;
map
2
map
4
map
6
map
8
map
10
- : unit = ()
```

No intermediate list is created.

However, in order to *sort* a collection, we have to traverse the entire thing anyway and barring a mutable collection, we have to build up a new collection. The laziness that sequences give us is nullified by that requirement. This is why you will not find a `sort` function in the [`Seq` module](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Seq.html).